# Clean up datasource results before calling it

Tags: angular, angular-material

When I click in a tab of my application a datasource is loaded with correct values but when I change tab and call same datasource with other parameter first, old values from previous tab are shown for a few seconds (5 sec.) before the values are replaced with the correct ones. How can I clear the `datasource` 
 results before calling it?. Thank you

```
ngOnInit() {
// Init DataSource
this.dataSourceProjectSteps = new ProjectStepsDataSource(this.projectStepsStore);
const entitiesProjectStepsSubscription = this.dataSourceProjectSteps.entitySubject.pipe(
   skip(1),
   distinctUntilChanged()
).subscribe();
this.subscriptions.push(entitiesProjectStepsSubscription);
this.subscriptions.push(entitiesProjectStepsSubscription);
this.selectedPId = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('selectedpId'), 10);
if (!isNaN(this.selectedPId)) {              this.formGroup.get('projectsCombo').setValue(this.selectedProjectId.toString());
  this.loadFeesPerStepByProject(this.selectedProjectId);
}

}

/**
* On Destroy
*/
ngOnDestroy() {
   this.subscriptions.forEach(el => el.unsubscribe());
}

loadFeesPerStepByProject(id: number) {
   this.projectStepsStore.dispatch(new ProjectDataByPhasePageRequested({projectId: id}));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe this can be use, this code for replace old value datasource with new value

```
constructor(service: myService) {

}

ngOninit() {
  this.dataSource = this.getFunctionOldValueDataSource();
  setTimeout(() => {
        this.dataSource = this.getFunctionNewValueDataSource();
  }, 5000);
}

getFunctionNewValueDataSource() {
   this.dataSource = [];
   tgus.service.getDataSourceNewValue();
}
```